# UITableView delegates not recognised after switching from UITableViewController to a UIViewController with separate UITableView

Tags: ios

My problem is that until now I used a `ViewController` and inside this I create the `UITableView` programatically. For this `ViewController` I have created a class named `WalkTroughViewController` and set it inside `Custom Class` inside `Identity Inspector`.

Now I have changed, and I create another `ViewController`(deleted the old one) and drag a `TableView` from the `Object Library`. Then I have set the `Custom Class` of this new `ViewController` to `WalkTroughViewController`, but now when I run the project my `UITableView` delegates are not called.

I have also dragged a `UITableViewCell` inside the `UITableView` and set it to my custom cell class.

Any pointers what I have done wrong ?

edit:

```
@interface WalktroughScreenViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

- (IBAction)nextScreen;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the crap out of Xcode? Also reset your simulator or delete the app from the simulator. I've run into problems with frankenbuilds after changing IBOutlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag and assign the delegate and the dataSource of the table in the story board to the fileOwner (Your Controller)

or simply assign it programatically in `ViewDidLoad` method

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: I have done that, still not working. I have added them in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: in you .h file ... beside your property declaration. Is the circle is filled or empty as shown in this image? http://www.image-share.com/upload/2357/45.png

Comment: I just realised, that it kinda works, I have implemented checkmarks on the cells, so if I press a cell, I can toggle the checkmark, but I don't know why the text is not appearing, but I guess your solution was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you assigned the delegate and the dataSource?

did you define

```
@interface YourClass: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Copy paste the code of your header so we can provide more help and see what's the issue

Comment: OK now make sure you connected your IBOutlet and after that just do what Hani responded. After this it should be working

Comment: Can you copy paste the code where you assign your delegate and data source?